# How does Spark create partitions of objects read from S3?

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3

How does Spark create partitions of objects read from S3?

I had an object in S3 with size 118MB. I read the object into a glue dynamic frame. Converted to spark dataframe and applied some transformations. Then wrote the data back to S3. The output folder consisted of two objects of sizes 51MB and 39MB.
How does Spark decide the partitioning scheme of the data read from S3?

The code is below:

```
df = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database = glueDatabase, table_name = glueTable).toDF()

df = df.filter('student.year != "2005"')

df.write.mode("append").json(s3WritePath)
```

Comment: the question is missing details on how the data was written back to S3. the code you used should be included.

Comment: Please add the code you are using. That will help people to understand the problem.

Comment: The code has been incoporated.

Answer (score 1):

When reading from s3 the default split size is 64 MB.
For eg. for 3 files as below, there splits will be as:

```
File size       Splits
100MB           64MB, 36MB
23MB            23MB
66MB            64MB, 2MB
```