# How distributed processing works with spark and S3?

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, distributed-computing

I have looked into detail on how distributed processing works with spark and HDFS. In that contrast I can see that the spark reads partitions as HFiles, and spark loads different HFiles to different partitions for parallel processing. But Iam concerned on how the same thing works in the case of object stores like s3.

Can someone help me understand

1. How distributed parellel processing works in the case of spark and object store like S3?
2. How partitions are created in this case?

Comment: Spark uses S3 prefix paths for partitions. `country=US/*` vs `country=CAN/*`

Comment: @oneCricketeer for a large object  say of size 20GB and configured partition size is less than that in Spark how is the partition created then

Comment: In S3, files aren't split like HDFS. The bucket has prefix paths, as mentioned. If you upload one 20 GB file to a bucket, then that will have no "partitions"

Comment: Would that effect the performance then?

Comment: It can be, but there's ways to optimize it. Most importantly, S3 is blob storage, not block storage like HDFS. There's a significant difference between those alone. However, Minio (which is S3 compatible), has some benchmarks that it's faster than HDFS. Ozone is also replacement for HDFS within Hadoop subprojects and S3 API compatible, I think

Comment: @OneCricketeer So is it safe to say that even today s3 , gcs , azure blob all these blob storages lack the performance of HFDS?

Comment: That's not what I said. I said that MinIO (which is a self-hosted version of S3 API) has published benchmarks that say they are faster than HDFS... But also, rack-local HDFS reads with YARN will be fastest of any option because there is no network lookup

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62584523/how-does-spark-create-partitions-of-objects-read-from-s3. Also is this answer wrong in then?

Comment: I never said anything about how S3 splits data. Only that it doesn't do it "like HDFS". The files themselves in the buckets are blobs. Not blocks. S3 doesn't split data written to the bucket into blocks... Doesn't mean that Spark doesn't read blobs using _multipart requests_